# How do I make a file accessible at the top level root?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

How do I make a file accessible at the top level root?

Basically, I want to be able to access foo.txt at https://www.sitename.com/foo.txt

Answer (score 2):

Just put it in your `public` folder. The Ember compiler will then just copy this file into your root on build.